# Creating planar slices of 3D object to quantify voids?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, 3d-analyst, multipatch

We are trying to quantify the void space in a 3D object, very similar to measuring the holes in cube of swiss cheese.  I need to measure cross sectional areas and study the shape of the voids and we will conduct the analysis on multiple objects.  The cube is a multipatch object currently stored in an Esri geodatabase.  We have ArcGIS, Polytrans, and MeshLab software and are hoping for a no cost solution.

By no cost, I do mean beyond the cost of software that we already own.  We do have 3D Analyst, as well as Maya and 3ds Max.

I have been working with the "cube" file and have determined that it is not a closed object. I am new to 3D processing so I may not be using the proper terminology.

Here is an image of the cube in question.

[image: The Cube]